# Javascript push() method alters values in a referenced array

Tags: javascript

So, this is working not as I'd expect it to:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = x;
y.push(4);
console.log(x);
```

I thought it'd log [1,2,3] but it logs [1,2,3,4]! What I need is to have a function that only adds a value to y, not x - I want to be able to mess around with the [1,2,3] array, but also be able to "come back to it" and cancel the changes made. I hope that makes enough sense...

Comment: One of those will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+copy+array.

Comment: Arrays are reference types, just like objects. It's the same as doing `var x = {}; var y = x; y.key = 'val'; console.log(x);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) --- with nearly the same example.

Comment: You're right, it's a duplicate, sorry guys I couldn't find it - should I delete this one, or let it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = x.slice();
y.push(4);
console.log(x);  // Outputs 1,2,3
```

Using `slice` is the simplest way to get a *copy* of an array.

Keep in mind that in Javascript `x` and `y` are *references* to arrays. In this, Javascript behaves differently than, for example, PHP.

So when you do `y.push(4)` you're pushing an element into the same array referenced by `x`.